# How can I create custom validation in HTML?

Tags: html, validation

I have multiple field in my form like

```
<input type="text" pattern="[0-9]+([\.,][0-9]+)?" step="any" oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Enter decimal value')" required>
```

can I create something like **required** ex **decimal** so that I do not have to write a pattern and custom message every time?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this,

- In case you have many fields having the same pattern you can either give the same class Name for all these fields,or the same name for all those fields,
- It would be necessary to do the above in order to identify all these kind of fields together,For example,

HTML Code:

```
<input type="text" step="any" class="patternText" oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Enter decimal value')" required>
```

JS Code:

```js
var patternFields=document.getElementByClassName("patternText");

for(var i=0;i<patternFields.length;i++) {
    patternFields.pattern="[0-9]+([\.,][0-9]+)?";
    patternFields.oninvalid = function(event) {
        event.target.setCustomValidity('Username should only contain lowercase letters. e.g. john');
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Based on Example [here](https://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addMethod/):

```
$.validator.addMethod('Decimal', function(value, element) {

    return this.optional(element) || /^\d+(\.\d{0,3})?$/.test(value); 

}, "Please enter a correct number, format xxxx.xxx");
```